# how to get excel to treat a date as a date not a string when doing CopyFromRecordset

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an SQL query from SQL Server which returns dates as a string in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".
If I enter a date in this format into a cell, it's recognised as a date.
But when I populate a worksheet with CopyFromRecordset, it seems to be treated as a string.
Any formula which uses the cell converts it to a date first. For example, if my dates are in col A and I make a new column B filled with a formula =A1 + 0 
the formula returns my date, as a date.

The problem: 
I use the Recordset data for a few things, one of them being a pivot table.
The pivot table does not see my dates as dates. I can't group as dates, for example. My hack is to make a new column which is basically =A1 + 0
I'm going to change my macro to automate this adding a zero, but I wonder if there's a way to get it right from the moment the CopyFromRecordset is performed.

Comment: Have you tried to manually assign the format of the cell to a "DATE" data type before the copyfromrecordset is applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do the conversion on the SQL server e.g.

```
SELECT CAST(date_text AS DATE) FROM TestExcelDates;
```

Comment: Note: this did not work for me in Oracle, so I just had to change the column's number Format in Excel.

Comment: casting as date did not work for me on sql server. Datetime did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`CopyFromRecordset` is well known for causing data type / cell formatting issues in Excel.

I think I remember reading somewhere this is because the datatype of the recordset is ignored and Excel attempts to work out the format of each column itself based on a subset of the data in the recordset.

The best way round this is to set the cell formatting in the destination range **before** performing the `CopyFromRecordset`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after I had changed a view on my SQL Server database.  I had changed the data type to DATE; formerly it was on an older version which didn't support DATE so I had used DATETIME.  I suspect Excel doesn't always recognize the Date datatype through the SQLOLEDB provider, but it does recognize DATETIME.  The field of interest is **meas_date**.  So I altered the view by changing this to a cast `SELECT CAST(meas_date AS DATETIME) AS meas_date, ...` and refreshed the query in Excel.  Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CDate()` function when populating cells with dates from the recordset.  This will convert the string to a date value.

**Edit**

That works for setting individual cell values.  For using `CopyFromRecordset` I think you need to do the conversino in the SQL query, so the column returned by the query is a date type rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too importing data from Teradata, and got around it by first formatting the date columns with NumberFormat = "m/d/yy h:mm;@" (24 hr date) then stepping through the date fields afterwards with VBA and doing ws.cells(iRow, iCol).value = ws.cells(iRow, iCol).value, it forces Excel to reevaluate the string into a date/time field.

Answer (score -1):

This probably will not be the answer but will surely helps you finding the right solution for your problem

```
String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();
```

here myCell has datatype as **CELL** which I've converted to **String** format.
If u want it in desired **Date** format, then u can try this-

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
myCellDate = sdf.parse(stringCellValue );
```

Hope it helps in solving your problem...